# Sleeping thread and thread initialization inside constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++03

Im trying to make a thread run out of a ctor , the thread should sleep , wake up and then perform a buffer dump and then sleep again and so on this is the code for the ctor:

```
 Logger::Logger()
 {
   BufferInUse = &CyclicBuffer1;                        //buffer 1 will be used at    beggining
   MaxBufferSize = 5;                                   //initial state
   NumOfCycles = 0;
   CurrentMaxStringLength = 0;

   position = BufferInUse->end();
   OutPutMethod = odBuffer;                         //by default
   Thresh = 1;                                      //by default

   hTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, TRUE, NULL);
   EventTime.QuadPart = -20000000;                          //1 second by default
   Mutex =  CreateMutex(NULL,FALSE,NULL);   
   if (Mutex == NULL) 
   { 
       OutputDebugStringA("CreateMutex error! the Logger will close \n");
       return ;
   }
   _beginthread( Logger::WorkerThread , 0,(void*)this );    //run the thread
}
```

when I debug it , it takes lots of time for the thread to even be created and finish the ctor function but in that time my object member functions get called lots of times (i see it when debugging). 
1.I want the thread to be created before my member functions get called, what is the best way to achieve that?

now my thread implementation is:

```
               void Logger::WorkerThread ( void *lpParam )
              {
                   Logger *log = static_cast <Logger*> (lpParam);
                   if (NULL == log->hTimer)
                   {
                      log->LogStringToOutput("CreateWaitableTimer() failed , Logger will close \n");
                       return;
                    }

               for(;;)
               {
                 //set timer for time specified by the EventTime variable inside the Logger
                 if (!SetWaitableTimer(log->hTimer, & (log->EventTime), 0, NULL, NULL, 0))
                 {
                     log->LogStringToOutput("SetWaitableTimer() failed , Logger will close\n" );
                    _endthread();
                 }

               //wait for timer
              if (WaitForSingleObject(log->hTimer, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
              {
                   log->LogStringToOutput("WaitForSingleObject() failed! Logger will close\n");
                  _endthread();
                  return;
              }

              if(log->getOutputMethod() == odBuffer && log->BufferInUse->size() >= log->Thresh && !log->BufferInUse->empty())
              {
                  TTFW_LogRet ret;
                 ret = log->FullBufferDump();
                 if (ret != SUCCESS)
                 {
                       log->LogStringToOutput("Error occured in dumping cyclic buffer , the buffer will be cleared\n");
                 }
             }
           }

        }
```

is there more elegant implementation of this thread functionality?

Comment: You should really use [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread), [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex), and [`std::this_thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/thread).

Comment: I cant since i have only VS 2008 and don't have license for a newer version , so i cant implement c++11 features

Comment: C++11 is C++.  You tagged your question C++, not C++03.  I have added the C++03 tag to make clear that you are unwilling or unable to use all of C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need some mechanism to synchronous WorkerThread starting and member function access.

for example, use a condition variable ([documents in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

add 3 member to Logger:

```
class Logger{
...

private:        
    CRITICAL_SECTION CritSection;
    CONDITION_VARIABLE ConditionVar;
    bool WorkerThreadStarted;

...
};
```

and

```
 Logger::Logger():WorkerThreadStarted(false)
 {
     EnterCriticalSection(&CritSection); //added

     BufferInUse = &CyclicBuffer1;    //buffer 1 will be used at    beggining

     ...
  }

 void Logger::WorkerThread ( void *lpParam )
 {

     WorkerThreadStarted=true; //added
     LeaveCriticalSection(&CritSection);

     Logger *log = static_cast <Logger*> (lpParam);
     if (NULL == log->hTimer)
     {
        log->LogStringToOutput("CreateWaitableTimer() failed , Logger will close \n");
         return;
     }


     ...
}
```

add such a function:

```
  void Logger::EnsureInitiallized(){

      EnterCriticalSection(&CritSection);

      // Wait until the predicate is TRUE

      while( !WorkerThreadStarted )
      {
         SleepConditionVariableCS(&ConditionVar, &CritSection, INFINITE);
      }

      LeaveCriticalSection(&CritSection);
  }
```

and at every member function's entry, call EnsureInitiallized();

```
  void Logger::yourFunction(){
    EnsureInitiallized();

    ...
  }
```

that is a example , you can also use a read_write lock , a atomic integer etc

Comment: it seems like a reasonable solution but it does not work , the program gets stuck on the SleepConditionVariableCS(&ConditionVar, &CritSection, INFINITE); line and it stays like this forever

Comment: oh, i made a mistake ,in WorkerThread, before LeaveCriticalSection, should not call Logger's member funtion, this will cause a self dead lock. i corrected it above.

Comment: its almost true , the WorkerThread is a static function so i pass the function a pointer to the object so i could access its members and if you declare the members as private members of the class you cant access them before you get the this pointer so you should at the beginning do the cast and then                    WorkerThreadStarted=true; //added
     LeaveCriticalSection(&CritSection);  or maybe declare those varables as static class members...